# MFC child dialog changing size unexpectedly

Tags: mfc, internationalization, dialog, resize

My application uses stacked dialogs to select between options in several places. For example, the dialog box below uses two stacked dialogs:

1. To choose between "shooting methods", the user selects from the drop-down list in the bottom right. This changes a child dialog box above it.
2. The "advanced options" box (located in the child dialog box) selects between a simplified interface and a more complete one.

[image: correct dialog]

In each case, the stacked dialog box is implemented using a picture object as a placeholder in the parent dialog. When a page is selected, SetWindowPos is called to move/resize the child dialog (pNewPage) to fit the placeholder.

```
// Show the newly selected page
pNewPage->ShowWindow (SW_SHOW) ;
pNewPage->SetFocus () ;

// Position the newly selected page
CRect rcDlgArea ;
GetDlgItem (IDC_DLG_AREA)->GetWindowRect (&rcDlgArea) ;
ScreenToClient (&rcDlgArea) ;

pNewPage->SetWindowPos (this, 
    rcDlgArea.left, rcDlgArea.top, rcDlgArea.Width (), rcDlgArea.Height (), 
    SWP_NOACTIVATE) ;
```

This has worked very well up until now, but one of my users in Germany is having a problem I can't explain. When he opens the tool, the stacked page comes up looking like this:

[image: incorrect dialog]

Note that the child dialogs are stretched so that the text in the child dialog appears larger than the text in the parent.

Other than the visual layout issues, the child dialog also seems to "cover" the selection drop-down in the bottom right (located in the parent dialog). Although the drop-down is still visible, CBN_SELCHANGE messages are not received when the drop-down list is clicked.

I am at a loss to explain why the child dialog boxes are being rescaled. As you can see above, I've tried to be very explicit about the resizing of the dialog box, but this doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone think of a reason why the child dialog might be rescaled on some systems but not on others? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Michael

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this user has larger fonts selected than what is used in the first screenshot. Note that dialog sizes are specified in DLU's, which scale with the size the user has selected for the font. You can either scale your dialog explicitly, in pixels (bad solution, this will make your app look even worse on some configurations), or do your calculations in DLU's everywhere. Your second screenshot also seems to show that the child dialogs use a different font than those of the wizard. I'm not sure why that is, I guess it's something in the window styles you pass to the wizard when you create it.

Comment: That's the thing that seems odd to me--the two different sizes. I thought DLUs would be consistent across the system. The user seems to think the system is stock, but that doesn't seem likely. I'd assumed that it was the child dialog font size that was wrong, but I'll check with the user which one matches the rest of the system.